# Find the constant $C$ for which $f$ is a density function

Tags: probability, integration, proof-verification, improper-integrals

Good afternoon, I'm doing **Exercise 2.19.3** about p.d.f function in a introductory probability course:

> [image]
>   [image]

Could you please verify if my proof looks fine or contains logical gaps/errors? Thank you so much for your help!

**My attempt:**

By Euler's substitution, let $\sqrt{x(1-x)} = xt$. Then $t \to +\infty$ as $x \to 0^+$ and $t \to 0$ as $x \to 1^-$.

$$\int_{0^+}^{1^-} (x(1-x))^{-1/2} \, \mathrm{d}x  = \int_{0^+}^{1^-} \dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x(1-x)}} \, \mathrm{d}x = \int_{0}^{+\infty} \dfrac{2}{1+t^2} \, \mathrm{d}t = \arctan (t) \Big|_0^{+\infty} = \frac{\pi}{2}$$

In order for $f$ to be p.d.f, $$\int_{0^+}^{1^-} C(x(1-x))^{-1/2} \, \mathrm{d}x  =1$$

This implies $$C\frac{\pi}{2} =1$$

Hence $C = 2/\pi$.

Comment: Hmm, Mathematica gives me $$\int_0^1 (x(1-x))^{-1/2} = \pi. $$

Comment: you forgot the $2$ when integrating to $\arctan$, so your result should be $\pi$, hence $C=\frac{1}{\pi}$

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing put my mistake @AsafRosemarin!